# Prove that if extensions $E_1$ and $E_2$ are isomorphic over $F$, $u$ is a root of $f(x)$ over $E_1$, then $\sigma(u)$ is a root over $E_2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field

Assume $F$ is a field, $E_1$ and $E_2$ are extensions of F, $\sigma:E_1 \rightarrow E_2$ is a field homomorphism, $f(x) \in F[x]$ is an irreducible polynomial. For any $a \in F$, $\sigma(a)=a$, i.e. $E_1$ and $E_2$ are isomorphic over $F$.

Prove that:  if $u \in E_1$ is a root of $f(x)$ over $E_1$, then $\sigma(u)$ is a root of $f(x)$ over $E_2$

Thought: For the root $u \in F \subseteq E_1$ it is obvious because $f(\sigma(u))=f(u)=0$, but how to extend to those roots $u \notin F$? Moreover, how to use the condition $f(x)$ is irreducible?

Comment: You won't need irreducibility of $f(x)$. The standard proof goes through without. Just write down $f(u)$ as an $F$-linear combination of powers of $u$. Then apply $\sigma$ to it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let

$f(x) = \displaystyle \sum_0^{\deg f} f_i x^i \in F[x]; \tag 1$

then

$f_i \in F, \; 0 \le i \le \deg f; \tag 2$

it follows that

$\sigma(f_i) = f_i, \; 0 \le i \le n; \tag 3$

then if

$f(u) = \displaystyle \sum_0^{\deg f} f_i u^i = 0, \tag 4$

we have

$f(\sigma(u)) = \displaystyle \sum_0^{\deg f} f_i (\sigma(u))^i = \sum_0^{\deg f} \sigma(f_i) (\sigma(u))^i = \sum_0^{\deg f} \sigma(f_i) \sigma(u^i)$
$= \displaystyle \sum_0^{\deg f} \sigma(f_iu^i) = \sigma \left (\sum_0^{\deg f} f_iu^i \right ) = \sigma(f(u)) = \sigma(0) = 0, \tag 5$

that is, $\sigma(u)$ is also a root of $f(x)$.

Note that, as pointed out by Jyrki Lahtonen in  his comment to the question itself, it is not necessary to assume $f(x)$ is irreducible to achieve this result.

Comment: Thanks. I wondered how to use $\sigma(a)=a$ on F, and it turns out I have made it too complicated. Plus, the irreducibility should be used in another question. Your solution definitely helps!

Comment: My pleasure my friend glad to be of service!  And thanks for the "acceptance"!  Cheers!